# How to find first editable control to focus on in a page

Tags: c#, asp.net

My current function only finds first Textbox which is not totally correct. Control class doesn't have IsEditable property.

```
    private static Control FindFocusableControl(Control CurrentControl)
    {
        if (CurrentControl.Visible)
        {
            if (CurrentControl is TextBox)
            {
                return CurrentControl;
            }
            if (CurrentControl.HasControls())
            {
                foreach (Control CurrentChildControl in CurrentControl.Controls)
                {
                    Control focusableControl = FindFocusableControl(CurrentChildControl);
                    if (focusableControl != null)
                    {
                        return focusableControl;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: @stuartd it's recursive, the method given *is* `FindFocusableControl`

Comment: @TJWolschon whoops, thanks!

Comment: Do you also want to check `if (CurrentControl.Enabled)`?

Comment: Control doesn't have enabled property.

Comment: Oh I was thinking of the [`System.Windows.Forms.Control` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control(v=vs.110).aspx). Are you talking about the [`System.Web.UI.Control` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control(v=vs.110).aspx)? What is the fully qualified name of `Control` (and `TextBox`) in the code you have posted?

Comment: Yes, it is for System.Web.UI.Control.

Answer (score 0):

On the first recursion for the first child control, the child control is probably not visible so the routine exits.

```
if (CurrentControl.Visible)
```

You might need a different kind of check at this point, perhaps check for textbox first, then if visible.